My not getting correct solution after checking condition is correct
I created the questions Like :

"What time did you go to bed?" Intent : bedtime set with
Parameters:
Parameter id: bedtime,
Entity type: @sys.date-time
Is list:
Redact in log:
"At what time did you wake up?" Intent : wakeup_time set with
Parameters:
Parameter id: wakeup_time,
Entity type: @sys.date-time
Is list:
Redact in log:
after this several 3 general questions with Yes/No intent, finally
It looks like you are finding it hard to stay asleep, is that correct?
Intent : Yes/No in this inside yes/no intent I gave the Condition rules--> Customize expression: " $sys.func.DATETIME_DIFF($session.params.wakeup_time, $session.params.bedtime, "HOURS") > 7"
So, After checking the condition I gave relevant solution as intent values in next page if it's more 7 hours it progress to more_than_7_hours solution and if it's less than 7 hours progress to less_than_7hours solution.

But it doesn't progress relevant solution
I created General_solution Page in that I gave two type of intents
more_than_7_hours
and
less_than_7_hours
So after checking the condition from previous page
$sys.func.DATETIME_DIFF($session.params.wakeup_time, $session.params.bedtime, "HOURS") > 7

